# Flutter Modal Sheet

Tags: flutter

I have seen and tried the '*showModalBottomSheet*' widget in flutter, and thought whether there was a widget like 'top sheet modal'. like whatsapp when a message comes in. as below,

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a 'top' modal sheet **inside** the app, you can use the [`Banner`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html) widget.

Otherwise, what is shown is screenshot is a notification which appears differently on iOS and Android.